# Accessing UIASCRIPT variable in UIAutomation test for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments, ios-ui-automation

Is there any way of accessing command line arguments of instruments in javascript test code?

I am starting a UI test using the following command:

> instruments -t
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Instruments/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -e UIASCRIPT abc.js

Answer (score 0):

I've used the tool for 1.5 months and there seems no such access.